# Changing CSS height on image not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cant change the height only the width works? I dont understand:)

```css
.image-size{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">   
  <div class="page-header">
 
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lexicon</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Java Fundamentals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Java Advanced</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Front-End</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test and Management</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Java Enterprise</a></li>
      
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  
 
  <div class="jumbotron">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
    <img class="thumbnail image-size" src="https://academy.oracle.com/en/oa-assets/i/c82/c82-java-prog-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive image-size">
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Im using bootstrap does i have anything to do with my problem? Why does the whole image change size when i just change the width.

Comment: Have u tried with the pixels instead of css

Comment: you defined attribute `class` twice in the tag `img`:     `<img class="thumbnail image-size" src="... ..." class="img-responsive image-size">`. You have to decide is it either thumbnail or img-responsive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because the Col that contain the img don't have height and you can't give % value to image because the parent don't have any height to get the 50% of that!
in other hand you can make it possible with "px";

```
.image-size{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

Or add height for container Col

Answer (score 2):

You should set specific height for parent of image (class=col-md-12)

For example:

```
.col-md-12{
  height: 100px;
}

.image-size{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can set height pixel it will work

```css
.image-size {
  height:300px;
  width :100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12" align="center">
    <img class="thumbnail image-size" src="https://academy.oracle.com/en/oa-assets/i/c82/c82-java-prog-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive image-size">
</div>
```

And if you want to set the height with percentage you have to set `position:absolute` to the image like

```css
.image-size {
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12" align="center">
    <img class="thumbnail image-size" src="https://academy.oracle.com/en/oa-assets/i/c82/c82-java-prog-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive image-size">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should provide height to parent first before assigning to a child.
You haven't set the  parents height . i.e. div's height so that it the  will know what 50% means.

```
<div class="col-md-12" align="center" style='height:100px'>
    <img class="thumbnail image-size" src="https://academy.oracle.com/en/oa-assets/i/c82/c82-java-prog-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive image-size">
</div>
```

I do not support inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css style

```
.thumbnail, .image-size, src {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%
}
```